# How to fix searchbar when switch from dark mode to light mode swift

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller, ios-darkmode

Hi I have a problem with searchbar.
I use this function to switch my app between dark and light mode

```
func changeStyle(dark: Bool){
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
      if dark == true {
          window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark 
      }else{
          window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
      }
}
```

All works fine but only search bar have a problem. Searchbar remains in dark mode when I switch to light mode. See image below
How can I fix it?

[image: App switched to light mode]

Answer (score 0):

Try listening for the change and set manually using `traitCollectionDidChange`:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
        //Set colours here
    }
}
```